# buildbot from start

Tags: python, buildbot

should be dumb as everybody seems to installed it without trouble.
I spent hours within a fresh squeeze and tried different configurations (easy_install, aptitude and from source 0.81p.tar.gz) the best I got is a page from the localhost:9989 
without any slave started.

Knowing that I made the 2 accounts : buildmaster and buildslave 
how to clean and reinstall it to have server and 1 slave for git ?

thanks in advance

---

Added :

You are right some details are missing:

I use buildbot from virtualBox with a Debian squeeze 6.0 in 32bits
The both accounts : buildmaster and buildslave are running within this same Virtual environment.

I just tried the little example (this seems really interesting) :
easy_install buildbot
buildbot create-master /tmp/experimental_buildmaster
buildbot start /tmp/experimental_buildmaster

1. as root the jinja2 was missing whereas from buildmaster there were no complain (??)
2. commented the Git calls that created errors to try to start the simplest demo
3. buildslave create-slave /tmp/experimental_buildslave 127.0.0.1:9989 slave-name mypasswd
4. in the log something appear allways : *"No address associated with hostname"*

it seems I'm closer with this no ?

Comment: Can you add more details?  What is your OS, are you running both the master and slave on the same box, etc.?

Comment: Actually installing it is easy, its the configuration that is the hard part, and no you are not dumb, as i also tried configuring it, and had trouble with it, still am. So i would like to track your progress

Comment: thanks Kamal, now I'm not the only one... Anyway I'm also happy that it will be usefull for you too. As helps -but take care that things are outdated- you may look at : [IBM presentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-buildbot/index.html#fig05)   and [mousebender](http://mousebender.wordpress.com/2006/05/26/installing-buildbot/)

Comment: It isn't clear what if any issues you are still having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people like kamal this may be usefull :

The little demo works now: 
- I did all as root with no build accounts. - easy_install buildbot 
- buildbot create-master /tmp/experimental_buildmaster

### most important is here

```
cp /tmp/experimental_buildmaster/master.cfg.example xperimental_buildmaster/master.cfg edit it
```

and pay attention to : **slavePortnum** default is :9989 and **git confs** : buildmaster will give errors with bad params

then

> buildbot start /tmp/experimental_buildmaster

wait for the "started sucessfully"

> easy_install buildbot-slave
>
> buildslave create-slave /tmp/experimental_buildslave localhost:9989 example-slave Password

I strongly disagree with the proposed ".. .. .."

> buildslave start /tmp/experimental_buildslave

and now for something completely different : open browser to localhost:8010

the welcome page is here, click buildslave to see your slave: rock'n roll !

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with the configuration, the [doc is pretty comprehensive](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/).  I only had a few problems with stuff more obscure than the doc can answer, at which point I turned to the nice folks - a number of their developers - on their IRC channel (`#buildbot` on [freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/)), who were very helpful.

Comment: I read re read the doc, whereas it's quite clear things are not those implemented. By the way, thanks for the link to the WebIRC !

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information about configuring abd running buildslave after it's creation.

After installing buildbot package int.d script */etc/init.d/buildbot* is added to enable running buildbot as a service (starting automatically after system restart and so on).

For this script to run successfully you need to edit conf file for this script. File name is specified inside the script, typically it is */etc/default/buildbot*. Options in this file are pretty clear. One interesting thing you can tune here - the user from which buildbot will be running (default is buildbot). Small example of when it is useful:

I had to write a buildbot task, one part of which was managing virtual machines running on builslave machine (starting, stopping, managing snapshots). But rights for doing this had only vbox user (I used Virtual Box VMs). So I simply changed the *user* field in */etc/buildbot/default* to accomplish this.

I hope this information will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [first run tutorial](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/tutorial/firstrun.html)?

- There is no reason to run buildbot as root (and reasons not to, as there have been a few security issues with buildbot). Depending on how you installed buildbot, the jinja2 dependency will be installed in different places. In particular, if you installed it using pip/easy_install not as root, then it is probably installed in your users directory, which root won't access by default.
- The slave will try to figure out its hostname. That might be causing the error you get about no hostname for address.